# How to make Canvas widget color darker compared to the original color?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, colors, widget, tkinter-canvas

I have this canvas widget with a green rectangle:

```
canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
canvas.create_rectangle(0,0,50,100, fill='green')
```

I want to darken it. So:

```
canvas.itemconfig(1, fill=?????)
```

The issue is, what should I put in the `?????` aka the 'darker' color of the original color.

Sure, I can just find a hex for a darker shade of green or something like that, but the point is: **How can I find the darkened the widget based on the original color?**

I don't necessarily need to find the darker version of the color if there is something like: `canvas.itemconfig(1, darkness=-100)`.

Comment: Have you tried `"darkgreen"`? Take a look at this [color chart](http://www.science.smith.edu/dftwiki/index.php/Color_Charts_for_TKinter) for Tkinter.

Comment: @Mike-SMT Sure, I can just find a hex for a darker shade of green or using preset like "darkgreen", but the point is: **How can I find the darkened the widget based on the original color?**

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example of how to use a function to lower the color based on a RGB tuple that is converted to hex. We start out with a lightish green and with each button press it gets darker. This is a simple example but I am sure you can adapt it for your needs.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

cv = (110, 160, 50)
canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
rect = canvas.create_rectangle(0,0,50,100, fill="#%02x%02x%02x" % cv)
canvas.pack()

def darker():
    global cv
    greater = True
    cv = (cv[0]- 10, cv[1] - 10, cv[2] - 10)
    for item in cv:
        if item < 0:
            greater = False

    if greater == True:
        canvas.itemconfig(rect, fill = "#%02x%02x%02x" % cv)

tk.Button(root, text="Darker", command=darker).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Or you can do this using the current preferred concatenation with `format()`:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

cv = (110, 160, 50)
canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
rect = canvas.create_rectangle(0,0,50,100, fill = "#{}".format("".join("{:02X}".format(a) for a in cv)))
canvas.pack()

def darker():
    global cv
    greater = True
    cv = (cv[0]- 10, cv[1] - 10, cv[2] - 10)
    for item in cv:
        if item < 0:
            greater = False

    if greater == True:
        canvas.itemconfig(rect, fill = "#{}".format("".join("{:02X}".format(a) for a in cv)))

tk.Button(root, text="Darker", command=darker).pack()

root.mainloop()
```